# form validation check if two fields are equal

Tags: javascript, validation

I have this javascript validation script that checks if the fields contain content and I have one validation script that checks if the two email fields have the same input but I would like to combine the two into one script so I only have to push one div with error messages

Part I (the one who checks if the field got any input at all)

```
function isValid(fldId,len) {
var fld = $("#"+fldId);
var val = fld.val();
window.console && console.log(fld,fldId)
if (val == "" || (len && val.length<len)) {
  fld.css("borderColor","red");
  return false;
}      
fld.css("borderColor","black");
return true;
}

$(function() {
$("form").on("submit",function() {
var errormessage = [];

if (!isValid('name')) {
  errormessage.push("error name");
}
if (!isValid('email')) {
  errormessage.push("error email");
}
if (!isValid('emailnogmaals')) {
  errormessage.push("error email again");
}  
if (errormessage.length>0) {
  window.console && console.log("error present");
  $(".error-messages").html(errormessage.join('<br/>')).fadeIn();
  return false;
}
window.console && console.log("success");
return true;
});
});
```

Part II (the one who checks if both fields have the same input)

```
function checkEmail(theForm) {
if (theForm.email.value != theForm.emailnogmaals.value)
{
    $(".error-message-email").text("• De e-mail adressen komen niet overeen").fadeIn();
    return false;
} else {
    return true;
}
}
```

Is it possible to combine the two?

Comment: ever looked at the jQuery validation plugin, takes care of all this and so much more [link here](http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/)

Comment: Thank you, even though it's not the direct solution to my problem it's better then I had

Comment: Cool, yeah I've writing form validation too many times and it is just nice to have these sort of things around, save your time to spend on things a bit more worthwhile. I'll post my suggestion as an answer should you feel so inclined to accept

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Writing javascript form validation always seems to be tedious, and to me always has the feeling of daja vu, I mean that was one of the first things that javascript was really ever used for, so I always feel like I'm reinventing the wheel. When you write It from scratch it seems to take a couple of iterations to get it just right anyway.

Regarding the wheel (i.e. the invention of it) I feel it was defined with the jQuery validation plugin ([link here](http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/)). It is quite a mature plugin (been around for bout 8 years or so) and works really well.
Validation includes but not limited to:
Required, min, max, range, email, number, date, creditcard, and equalTo (comparing fields). You can also add your own rules for validation.

You do have to spend a bit of time getting to know it (i.e. how it does things, notably the attributes it uses and the class names it gives the validation errors), but once you do, you can easily use it again and again, changing styling each time you use it if you wish

Answer (score 0):

You should give the field 'email' and 'emailnogmaals' an ID.
lets say we give them the ID's email and emailnogmaals:

```
    function isValid(fldId,len) {
    var fld = $("#"+fldId);
    var val = fld.val();
    window.console && console.log(fld,fldId)
    if (val == "" || (len && val.length<len)) {
      fld.css("borderColor","red");
      return false;
    }      
    fld.css("borderColor","black");
    return true;
    }

    $(function() {
    $("form").on("submit",function() {
    var errormessage = [];

    if (!isValid('name')) {
      errormessage.push("error name");
    }
    if (!isValid('email')) {
      errormessage.push("error email");
    }
    if (!isValid('emailnogmaals')) {
      errormessage.push("error email again");
    }

//-------------------------Check for equal mail
    if ($('#email').Text() != $('#emailnogmaals').Text())
    {
       errormessage.push("emails are not equal");
    }
//-------------------------Check for equal mail

    if (errormessage.length>0) {
      window.console && console.log("error present");
      $(".error-messages").html(errormessage.join('<br/>')).fadeIn();
      return false;
    }
    window.console && console.log("success");
    return true;
    });
    });
```

Comment: thank you for your quick answer! But it doesn't work.. adding this even skips the whole validation process now

Comment: add this to your head: `<head>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
</head>`